# Binding to a ScrollViewer's ViewportWidth and ViewportHeight

Tags: c#, wpf, height, width, scrollviewer

I am using the Model-View-ViewModel architecture in a WPF application I am building, and I would like a specific ViewModel to actually be reactive to the size of the view (not a normal use-case of the MVVM approach, I know).

Essentially, I have a ScrollViewer object and I want the viewmodel to observe the width and height of the scrollviewer and then be able to do things accordingly depending on what that width and height are.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer ViewportWidth="{Binding Path=MyViewportWidth, Mode=OneWayToSource}" ViewportHeight="{Binding Path=MyViewportHeight, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

But of course this is impossible to do because "ViewportWidth" and "ViewportHeight" cannot be "bound to" (a.k.a. act as binding targets) because they are read-only dependency properties (even though I am not writing to them at all in this binding since it is OneWayToSource).

Anyone know of a good method to be able to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running something OnLoaded or OnResizeChanged that updates the viewmodel

```
private void ScrollViewer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ScrollViewer sv = sender as ScrollViewer;
   ViewModel vm = sv.DataContext as ViewModel;

   vm.ScrollViewerHeight = sv.ViewportHeight;
   vm.ScrollViewerWidth = sv.ViewportWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a *really* old question, but I thought I'd share for posterity, since I've solved this one myself.  The best solution I've found is to create a user control that derives from the ScrollView class and implements the properties you want - which are of course linked to the non-bindable properties of the base class.

You can use the OnPropertyChanged function to monitor those properties and keep the values in sync.

Here's the full code-behind of my custom usercontrol called DynamicScrollViewer.  Notice that I have four bindable dependency properties called DynamicHorizontalOffset, DynamicVerticalOffset, DynamicViewportWidth, and DynamicViewportHeight.

The two offset properties allow both read and write control of the offset, while the viewport properties are essentially read-only.

I had to use this class when creating a complex animation editor control in which various components (labels at the left, nodes in the middle, timeline at top) needed to scroll synchronously, but only in limited aspects, and were all bound to common external scrollbars.  Think of locking a section of rows in spreadsheet, and you get the idea.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace CustomControls
{
    public partial class DynamicScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
    {
        public DynamicScrollViewer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public double DynamicHorizontalOffset
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(DynamicHorizontalOffsetProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DynamicHorizontalOffsetProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DynamicHorizontalOffsetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DynamicHorizontalOffset", typeof(double), typeof(DynamicScrollViewer));

        public double DynamicVerticalOffset
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(DynamicVerticalOffsetProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DynamicVerticalOffsetProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DynamicVerticalOffsetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DynamicVerticalOffset", typeof(double), typeof(DynamicScrollViewer));

        public double DynamicViewportWidth
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(DynamicViewportWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DynamicViewportWidthProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DynamicViewportWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DynamicViewportWidth", typeof(double), typeof(DynamicScrollViewer));

        public double DynamicViewportHeight
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(DynamicViewportHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DynamicViewportHeightProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DynamicViewportHeightProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DynamicViewportHeight", typeof(double), typeof(DynamicScrollViewer));

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
            if (e.Property == DynamicVerticalOffsetProperty)
            {
                if (ScrollInfo != null)
                    ScrollInfo.SetVerticalOffset(DynamicVerticalOffset);
            }
            else if (e.Property == DynamicHorizontalOffsetProperty)
            {
                if (ScrollInfo != null)
                    ScrollInfo.SetHorizontalOffset(DynamicHorizontalOffset);
            }
            else if (e.Property == HorizontalOffsetProperty)
            {
                DynamicHorizontalOffset = (double)e.NewValue;
            }
            else if (e.Property == VerticalOffsetProperty)
            {
                DynamicVerticalOffset = (double)e.NewValue;
            }
            else if (e.Property == ViewportWidthProperty)
            {
                DynamicViewportWidth = (double)e.NewValue;
            }
            else if (e.Property == ViewportHeightProperty)
            {
                DynamicViewportHeight = (double)e.NewValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```